# Leaflet map not filling entire wrapper div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, leaflet, sidebar

I am a bit of a novice when it comes to HTML/bootstraps etc.  I'm having an issue where a div (a Leaflet map) is not filling the wrapper div completely.  Basically, I have a sidebar, which can be toggled on and off, and the map itself.

Here's my basic HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>Genre</h3>
            <input type="radio" name = 'genre' id="allGenre" checked> All<br>
        </div>

    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    <span>Filter Events</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
            <!-- Map! -->
            <div id="map" style="min-width: 100vh; min-height: 100vh" pointer-events="all"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, a snippet of the relevant CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#map{
}

#content{   
}

#sidebar {
    /* don't forget to add all the previously mentioned styles here too */
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;

}
  
#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;

}
```

My issue is that the map isn't filling the wrapper div completely.  I have tried setting the content div (which contains the map div) to 100vh, assuming that would fill the entire wrapper, but no luck.  Screen shots here:

[image][image]

You can see that the map is filling up the entire content div, but the content div isn't filling up the entire outer wrapper div, which is causing that gap / whitespace.  How can I get the content to fully fill the wrapper, while maintaining the sidebars existing appearance?

Comment: What happens if you add `#content { width:100%; }`

Answer (score 1):

it's because of the magic of flexbox. You can tell the browser to fill the remaining space by the #content element like this:

```
#content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all.  APAD1, your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you.  Johannesdz, I have not tried your solution but thank you!